# Using a neural network to forecast on time series with a variable horizon

Tags: neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I have used ANNs to classify data before, but not for time series data. Basically I want to know the possibility (relative ease) for a neural network to take a bunch of previous time series data, then be able to predict into the future for not just a single point in time (for which it's been trained), but for an arbitrary point in time (up to certain limits, of course)

is the best/simplest way to train a bunch of ANNs, each one targeting different time horizons (e.g. 1 hours, 2 hours, 5 hours, 24 hours), then if you want a prediction for another time, say 3 hours, use something like interpolation to try and forecast?

How can I structure my problem to handle this? Is there a particular neural network design that is suited to this application. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is too broad a question. It sounds like you are interested in financial or maybe weather forecasting. Those issues are incredibly complex; people have written thousands of pages describing research into how best to tackle these types of problems. So, your question really doesn't fit the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: This question belongs to StackExchange. Try there.